# JS SDK Performance testing

Tags: javascript, performance-testing, web-frontend

We have complex JS SDK, that provides rich set of client-side functionality for adding and processing Consumer data. Basically, is our main integration point for the web sites and the Data management layer. Functional testing is already covered, but now we face the need to continuously performance test the SDK.

How we can do that, so we address JS SDK's:

- Speed - Determines whether the SDK responds quickly
- Scalability - Determines maximum user load the SDK can handle (maybe multiple tabs in same session, submitting/fetching heavy data from the backend?)
- Stability - Determines if the SDK is stable under varying loads (multiple requests under same session)

**Note**, that this is not a typical Performance testing of a Web application. I'm not looking for how quickly basic page features load, like layout or when the functional elements become responsive to carry out user requests.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [User Timing API](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webperformance/usertiming/)? Once you have exposed component  load values using User Timing API. You could use tools like WebPageTest.org or Selenium to extract the values you need from DOM. Perhaps combine it with a load test so you can see the impact on UI under load.

Please be careful when measuring client performance will be dependant on 
a) the device specifications on which you are running the tests on
b) what other processes you have running in the background.

So you need a synthetic tool which can consistently measure the metrics you want to monitor. Running it locally might give you different results based on what else you have running in the background.

Comment: this solution is more oriented to serve in a tuning-change and retest cycles. Before that point, I need to understand if the JS SDK meets its performance objectives.

Comment: Have you considered using Google Chrome Dev Tools JavaScript profiler for this? You can review how much resources you frontend JavaScript is using especially the CPU and break it down to calls. Here is a link for Chrome 58 (has been many improvements since then) which might give you an overview https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/devtools-javascript-cpu-profile-migration